# How can I get the error from a callback function? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, callback

I want to catch the error from "revokeToken" function and return it as json response in the api.post . But I'm not getting how this to be done. Can anyone help me out with this? Is there any better way of wring it?

```
app.post('/api/logout', (req, res)=>{
    var request = new Request(req);
    var response = new Response(res);

    var tokenArray = request.headers.authorization.split(" ");
    var token = tokenArray[1];
    var tokenObj = {
        accessToken : token
    }
    let errmsg = '';
    revokeToken(tokenObj, (obj)=>{
        errmsg = obj;
    });
    res.json({
        data: null,
        result:{
            isError: false,
            status: 200,
            errorMsg: errmsg
        }
    });
 });


var revokeToken = function(token, callback) {
    tokenModel.deleteOne({
        accessToken: token.accessToken
    }).exec((function(callback, err, results) {
        var deleteSuccess = results && results.deletedCount === 1;
        let result = '';
        if (!deleteSuccess) {
            return err;
            }
        else{
            return err;

        }
    }).bind(null, callback));
    callback("Token Deleted!")
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the error object by passing the `msg` property as parameter to the `callback` function.
Also, rename the `exec` function callback to something other than `callback`:

```
var revokeToken = function (token, callback) {
  tokenModel
    .deleteOne({
      accessToken: token.accessToken,
    })
    .exec(
      function (done, err, results) {
        var deleteSuccess = results && results.deletedCount === 1;
        let result = '';
        if (!deleteSuccess) {
          callback(err.msg);
          return;
        }
        callback('Token Deleted!');
      }.bind(null, callback)
    );
};
```